# Elements in beginning or end of an array in Binary Search

Tags: search, binary

I have been trying to understand the binary search algorithm which is quite simple but I have one question which is bothering me. I might have understand it wrong.

1) When we start searching for an element in an array, we checked three scenarios
i) If the element is in the middle.
ii) If it is greater then middle element. 
iii) If it less then the middle element.

My question is I understand this algorithm tries to find the element by diving the array and using the above check pints but what if the element we are searching for is in the beginning or end of array. for example if

a = {12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 , 19, 20} ;

and we are looking for number 12 then why would it has to do all the divide and checking when it can find it in the first element of array. Why don't we also check the starting and end element of every binary search iteration instead of just only three scenarios stated above?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know where an element is, why bother searching at all? It's general purpose searching algorithm, and assumes no knowledge of the contents to be searched. If you know the contents, and you know which item you're interested in, you don't need a search anymore. What if we're looking for the number 14? Why doesn't it check every second element instead of just the 3 scenario's?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand we assume no prior knowledge of element position in the search, but what I mean to ask is that when we are searching for an element why don't we also check that it can be at the end or start of an array. I think that way we can stop the search in the beginning. Let suppose we have 1 million elements in an array and the element is just at start of any array why bother dividing it and comparing it?  I am working on an array where after two iteration the start became the target element but since we only checked the middle element I couldn't wrap it up.

Comment: Because it's a general purpose searching algorithm. It might as well check the 78234th element of a million element array to see if that's the one. Nothing special about the 1st element, *unless you have specific knowledge about the contents*.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Before the very first iteration I think it makes more sense to check the first and last index of an array for the targeted element and then begin the binary search. For when this situation comes in the middle of search I will try to implement what I am thinking and compare the time stamp for both methods in these situations. Thanks anyway willem!!.